# How are transaction IDs generated and how are they then changed by transaction malleability?

Tags: transaction-malleability, transaction-id

How are the transaction IDs generated for a Bitcoin transaction? How can the transaction ID change due to a transaction malleability attack?

Comment: Related answer: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/21995/3041

Comment: it doesn't answer my question, i already know what malleability is. I want to know how to generate the transaction id (what the actual data is before generating id) and how data is modified to get a new id

Comment: related: [How do I calculate the txid of this raw transaction?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/32765/5406), [Why does txID generation consider signatures?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/34009/5406)

Answer (score 4):

The transaction ID is the `SHA256d(signedTransaction) = SHA256(SHA256(signedTransaction))`. Sha256d is SHA256 applied two times.

Example:
Let us consider the transaction with ID [844c00ca065bc26eb61bfee203df2f7bcbc72a6bb77697a32d2a98dad5941109](http://chainquery.com/bitcoin-api/getrawtransaction/844c00ca065bc26eb61bfee203df2f7bcbc72a6bb77697a32d2a98dad5941109/0). The hex encoding of this transaction is:

```
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
```

You can check that the SHA256d for this signedTransaction is `091194d5da982a2da39776b76b2ac7cb7b2fdf03e2fe1bb66ec25b06ca004c84` on this page:
http://extranet.cryptomathic.com/hashcalc/index (remember to tick the 'Enter as hex' box) by flipping the endianness (Bitcoin uses small-endian representation of hex numbers/byte arrays), you get the expected result:

```
844c00ca065bc26eb61bfee203df2f7bcbc72a6bb77697a32d2a98dad5941109
```

Transaction malleability means that you can change the signedTransaction without invalidating it. So someone else has provided the signature but you can change the signed transaction in some way without invalidating the provided signature.

A Bitcoin transaction consists of different fields such as inputs, output amounts, output destinations etc. One of the fields is called scriptSig and this is where the signature goes.

It is possible to change the scriptSig field without invalidating the signature. The scriptSig field consists of instructions (opcodes) where a signature is considered valid if the execution of the scriptSig field followed by the execution of the scriptPubKey field (another field consisting opcodes) leaves the number `1` on top of the stack. The virtual machine that executes the opcodes is a stack machine.

For example you can add the op code `OP_NOP` (which does nothing) in front of the rest of the scriptSig without invalidating the signature. The signed transaction may still be picked up by miners but the transaction ID (once it is included on the blockchain) will be different than what the signer expects.

Segregated witness transactions solve this problem by removing the signature from the scriptSig field into a new field called the witness field and it also prevents any additional data from entering the scriptSig field thus preventing the malleability. The TXID of a segwit transaction is calculated the same way but it does not include the new field, the witness.